# How to check whether a device supports User's Contacts or not?

Tags: android, user-permissions

I used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` and

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />` in my application's manifest. And read the user's contacts

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent,1000);
```

Does `READ_CONTACTS` permission can filter the application in Google Play?

What happens if we tried to access the Contacts if there is no Contacts .For eg: Some tablets does not have Contacts and Phone functionality.What happens in this case? Does this code will crash?

If code will cash then how to check whether device supports contacts or not?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check, if there is an activity to handle the Intent:

```
Context context = /* whatever suits your case: this/getActivity/.. */
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivityForResult(intent,1000);
} else {
     // no Contacts app available
}
```

Comment: Does this application will be compatible for devices which does not have Contacts App?

Comment: flx i have a doubt too. Also I have two broadcast receivers in my application for listening incoming & outgoing call states And they are specified in manifest and one of them started through code. So i used <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> and checked getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) before starting the receiver from code

Comment: You need to check every call agains APIs like this. That's all.

Comment: If you need to be sure, then test your app on devices without contacts app. But you can trust me in this case and accept the answer.

Comment: Please let me to conclude, these two changes can make my app visible for all devices in Android market eventhough they have not Phone & Contacts functions, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a play store filter which checks if you are launching the Contacts app. And that's what this question is about. My answer will make your app work, even if there is no Contacts app available, why ever that will be.

Comment: @flx i tried this code  but it doesnt work,do i have to give any permissions?